# Magento 2 override product collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I need to override

`protected function _productLimitationPrice($joinLeft = false)` 
in magento 2 which is located at 
`public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php` 
 How can i override method in product collection.

```
class Collection extends 
           \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection

       {
      protected function _productLimitationPrice($joinLeft = false)
   {
      $filters = $this->_productLimitationFilters;
    if (!$filters->isUsingPriceIndex() ||
        !isset($filters['website_id']) ||
        (string)$filters['website_id'] === '' ||
        !isset($filters['customer_group_id']) ||
        (string)$filters['customer_group_id'] === ''
    ) {
        return $this;
    }

    // Preventing overriding price loaded from EAV because we want to use the one from index
    $this->removeAttributeToSelect('price');

    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $select = $this->getSelect();
    $joinCond = join(
        ' AND ',
        [
            'price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id',
            $connection->quoteInto('price_index.website_id = ?', $filters['website_id']),
            $connection->quoteInto('price_index.customer_group_id = ?', $filters['customer_group_id'])
        ]
    );

    $fromPart = $select->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::FROM);
    if (!isset($fromPart['price_index'])) {
        $least = $connection->getLeastSql(['price_index.min_price', 'price_index.tier_price']);
        $minimalExpr = $connection->getCheckSql(
            'price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL',
            $least,
            'price_index.min_price'
        );
        $colls = [
            'price',
            'tax_class_id',
            'final_price',
            'minimal_price' => $minimalExpr,
            'min_price',
            'max_price',
            'tier_price',
        ];

        $tableName = [
            'price_index' => $this->priceTableResolver->resolve(
                'catalog_product_index_price',
                [
                    $this->dimensionFactory->create(
                        CustomerGroupDimensionProvider::DIMENSION_NAME,
                        (string)$filters['customer_group_id']
                    ),
                    $this->dimensionFactory->create(
                        WebsiteDimensionProvider::DIMENSION_NAME,
                        (string)$filters['website_id']
                    )
                ]
            )
        ];

        if ($joinLeft) {
            $select->joinLeft($tableName, $joinCond, $colls);
        } else {
            $select->joinLeft($tableName, $joinCond, $colls);
        }
        // Set additional field filters
        foreach ($this->_priceDataFieldFilters as $filterData) {
            $select->where(call_user_func_array('sprintf', $filterData));
        }
    } else {
        $fromPart['price_index']['joinCondition'] = $joinCond;
        $select->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::FROM, $fromPart);
    }
    //Clean duplicated fields
    $this->_resourceHelper->prepareColumnsList($select);

    return $this;

  }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with _productLimitationPrice method?

Comment: i need to changed the product collection to display grouped products with out simple products associated.in magento 2.2.5 , if we add a grouped products there is an entries added in catalog_product_index_price with price values as null , when we read product collection there are using inner join with  catalog_product_index_price table , so that the  grouped products without simple products are displaying in list pages.

Comment: But in magento 2.2.6 when we create a grouped product there are no entries in catalog_product_index_price table ,when an simple product is assigned then entries are entered in database. Due to this grouped products without simple are not displaying in frontend. We need to change the collection that instead of inner join we use left join to get the products in list pages.

Comment: did you run di:compile?

Comment: yes i ran di:comile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**_productLimitationPrice method** is protected so you can not able to make a plugin.

So you have to override by preference method

**public_html/app/code/vendor/module/etc/di.xml**

add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection"/>
</config>
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection.php**

```
_productLimitationPrice(){

    make your custom code
}
```

Comment: But it is not working

Comment: @Prasanth Can you please add your Collection.php code in question

Comment: Thanks for helping. I added collection in question.